# Varnish with apache 2 and multi vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish, magento

I am looking to a guide about configure Varnish for my ubuntu server with apache 2.

There is like 20 website (who are not using varnish and do not need it).

Only one vhost (magento 2.X) need varnish.

Two problem :
The port is 443 (ssl) and When I set up the configuration, all websites stop working..

Any idea or tips, even manual would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ports of Apache because the proxy needs to allocate http(s) in order to intercept the traffic.